# ¿Se puede saber que archivo estoy viendo en la herramienta de desarrolladores del navegador?

Tags: wordpress, localhost

como estan? Estoy desarrollando un e-commerce en Wordpress desde mi localhost y necesito entrar al codigo fuente. Cuando toco un elemento desde la herramienta para desarrolladores del navegador puedo ver lo que seria el html o el php (el principal supongo). Mi pregunta va a si puedo saber el nombre del archivo de ese codigo que estoy viendo, y en todo caso su ubicacion. Saludos!

Comment: el archivo principal que se muestra es el index, si quieres ver los archivos ve a la parte de Sources y en la parte izquierda en vez de ```contet script``` selecciona ```pages```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay un plugin llamado [What the File](https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/) el cual cuando lo instalas y activas aparece en la barra de administrador el archivo en el que estas, solo que solo te muestra la plantilla como tal y te deja ir al editor si ese archivo esta en la carpeta de themes, mostrara plantillas de plugins tambien pero no te permitirá ir a ellas por lo que tendrás que buscarlos manualmente, de todas formas es mas fácil sabiendo el nombre del archivo el rastrearlo, también toma en cuenta que si es mediante shortcode no detectara el archivo.php del shortcode si no de la plantilla actual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra forma es viendo las clases del body, generalmente suele estar el nombre de la plantilla.

Comment: Sos crack!! Mil gracias, ya pude solucionar con ese plugin el problema que quería solucionar hace rato :D

Answer (score 1):

si quieres ver los archivos ve a la parte de Sources y en la parte izquierda en vez de `contet script` selecciona `pages`
[image: ver archivo]

Comment: Gracias Christian por responder. Si esa opcion la vi pero no me aparecia el nombre real del archivo, sino que me decia index pero no era el archivo index. Lo solucione con el plugin de la respuesta anterior, que de hecho me manda al editor de codigo que hay dentro de Wordpress.

Comment: lo importante es que pudiste solucionar tu problema :)